# angularjs Scope is losing value?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a form that intakes an address along with some other data.  I would like to send the address through google geocode for lat and long. then pass all the data into my db. So I can perform all the actions on their own and everything works. BUT when I tried to combine everything $scope.data.address returns undefined. Thank you for any help you can provide a noob.

```
  var date = new Date();
    $scope.date = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'MMMM dd, yyyy');

     $scope.data = {     
        date:        $scope.date,  
        claim:       $scope.claim,
        name:        $scope.name,
        address:     $scope.address,
        notes:       $scope.notes
      };



    $scope.addClaim = function () {

       // get address from input form and covert to latitude longitude
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        if (geocoder) {
            geocoder.geocode({
                'address': $scope.data.address
            }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    $scope.lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    $scope.long = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    console.log($scope.data.address)
                    console.log('lat' + results[0].geometry.location.lat())
                    console.log('long' + results[0].geometry.location.lng())


        // push new record to firebase
        firebase.database().ref('/claim/').push({

           date:        $scope.data.date,
           claim:       $scope.data.claim,
           name:        $scope.data.name,
           address:     $scope.data.address,
           notes:       $scope.data.notes,
           lat:         $scope.lat,
           long:        $scope.long


        });
        // end firebase
                }
            });
        }
       // end convert address
```

Comment: You have to post more code specially where $scope.data is used, also you can try watching that to see when it gets changes and trace the caller function

Comment: Where is the address being "lost". I assume when you `console.log($scope.data.address)`, it prints `undefined`. What happens if you `console.log($scope.data.address)` before instantiating the Geocoder object?

Comment: Yaser, I add more code but that is really the end of it. It is really basic.

Comment: GPicazo without Geocoder I can log everything correct to console.log

Comment: what is the purpose of mapping to your $scope.data object?  why not just use $scope.data.whatever in your ng-models in your form?  this will two-way bind it and you won't have to  map like you are.  i.e. `<input name="address" ng-model="data.address"/>`

Comment: Thank you for your reply big_water.  Are you suggesting the way I'm mapping the data is affecting the binding as it passes through Geocoder ?  If so can you please explain why. I'm learning and appreciate the time and guidance this group provides.

Comment: **Solved** Thanks for the time everyone.